# Filter product search by category

Tags: magento2, search, catalogsearch

I'm trying to filter my product search by returning only products within the current category I'm in, I can't find where the product collection is created within the search module

Can anyone help point me in the right direction?

Comment: Please confirm whether you would like to filter products by  category id ?

Comment: @NAGARAJUKASA Yes that's right!

Comment: just i am giving u sample prototype script with the example let's try and get back with u r suggestions thanks

Comment: @NAGARAJUKASA Thank you, when i run this is just redirects me to the homepage, do I put it within my theme or in the whole file root (public_html/test.php) ?

Comment: you have to keep in magento 2 root folder ex: http://prntscr.com/g1d98w

Answer (score 1):

Please run the below code in the default magento2 at root **(test.php)**, Here i am giving u sample example with the filter options and returning the collection array.

```
<?php
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$state = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');


$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$cateid = '9';
$cateinstance = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory');
$allcategoryproducts = $cateinstance->create()->load($cateid)->getProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH)
->addAttributeToFilter('status',\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED);
echo  "<pre>";
echo count($allcategoryproducts);?>
```